# Сохранение паролей с обеспечением целостности

Tags: c#, безопасность, защита, пароль

Как можно сохранять пароли в локальном приложении. У меня есть приложение на C# в VS, требующее пароль при входе, после входа пароль можно изменить, но вопрос возникает в том, как сохранить этот пароль. Я знаю про хэширование и шифрование, но каким образом защитить файл с паролем от, например, удаления или изменения данных в нем?

Answer (score 2):

В локальном приложении - никак. Если и правда нужна защита - делайте клиент-серверное приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей подойдёт [Cryptography API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и [Windows Data Protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). Примеры использования этого API, в основном, на C/C++, но я думаю не должно составить проблемы перевести это на C# или же найти обёртку.

Есть [статья](https://rsdn.ru/article/crypto/cryptoapi.xml) по использованию этого API на русском,

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace Forms
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            check_similar ();//проверяет соответствие сохраненного пароля и введенного(авторизация)
            //список имеющихся функций и их смысл:
            //check_enter();проверяет есть ли резервный файл пароля и проверяет пароль из этого файла.

            //Safe(); создает хэш для введенных данных
            /*controller ();проверяет был ли удален файл с паролем из проводника если да,
                            то читает данные из скрытого файла и проверяет 
                            пароль(если удалить скрытый файл,то ничего не будет работать, это сделано специально)*/

            //look (); если отсутствуют все нужные для пароля файлы, то они создаются и предлагают придумать пароль.
        }

        static void look()
        {
            string create = "conf", security = "control", text;
            Console.Write ("Придумайте пароль   -->   ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (text.Length < 9) {
                Console.Write ("Слишком короткий. ");
                look ();
            }else{
                using (MD5 crypt = MD5.Create ()) {
                    string data = Safe (crypt, text);
                    File.WriteAllText (create, data);
                    File.SetAttributes (create, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

                    File.WriteAllText (security, data);
                    File.SetAttributes (security, FileAttributes.Hidden);
                }
            }
        }

        static void controller(){
            string create = "conf", security = "control";
            if (!File.Exists (create)){
                string read = File.ReadAllText (security);
                File.WriteAllText (create, read);
                File.SetAttributes (create, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            } else {
                Console.Write ("File is exists! ");
            }
        }


        static string Safe(MD5 crypt, string input){
            byte[] code = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input));    
            StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder ();
            for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++) {
                strings.Append (code[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return strings.ToString (); 
        }

        static void check_similar(){
            string security = "control", data_check, data_enter;
            if (File.Exists (security)) {
                Console.Write ("Для входа ведите пароль! --->   ");
                data_check = Console.ReadLine ();
                using (MD5 crypt = MD5.Create ()) {
                    data_enter = Safe (crypt, data_check);
                    if (data_enter == File.ReadAllText (security)) {
                        controller ();
                    } else {
                        Console.Write ("Неверно! Попробуйте еще! \n");
                        check_similar ();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                look ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```